# How to download all version of Firefox for Ubuntu and Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, firefox

Here I wanted to download the older version of Firefox from repository but repository itself does not seems to have the older version of Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

You can download all version of firefox from below link for both windows and linux.

http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/